# Вычисляемое поле в code first подходе

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Добрый день!
Есть код класса:

```
public class Manager
{
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public string ManagerFirstName { get; set; }
    public string ManagerLastName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public List<Department> Department { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ManagerFullName
    {
        set
        {
           ManagerFullName = ManagerLastName + ManagerFirstName;
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу получить доступ к ManagerFullName - не выводится значение.
Вот код combobox

```
                var managers = db.Managers;
            ListManagers.ItemsSource = managers.ToList();
            ListManagers.DisplayMemberPath = "ManagerFullName";
            ListManagers.SelectedValuePath = "ManagerId";
```

Где я ошибся?
Спасибо.

Comment: У вас ведь нет геттера для свойства ManagerFullName, вы сами запретили читать его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепишите так:

```
public string ManagerFullName
{
    get
    {
       return ManagerLastName + ManagerFirstName;
    }
}
```

Вы перепутали геттер с сеттером

Или тоже самое более кратко:

```
public string ManagerFullName => ManagerLastName + ManagerFirstName;
```

Comment: Благодарю вас! Я просто видимо не совсем понял идеологию.